# Data transformation in MS Integrations Services

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, etl

I'm using MS Integrations Services and I have a package that from an sql query returns a date & time field. From this source, I have to extract the hour from the date & time field. Once I get the hour, I need to create the following relationship:

```
Hour    Reff.
<3      0
<6      1
<9      3
...
```

I have to save the date & time field and a new Reff. field a destination table.

I tried using a 'Derived Column Transformation Editior' module, but I'm not sure what to use as a Derived Column and Expression.

I tried to use the following Expression:

```
datepart(hh,[Date_Time])
```

This appears in red with different errors (Can not parse the expression, Expression is not valid,...) and in any case it would only give the hour.

Would someone know whow can I achieve the required trasnformation?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error in your formula. It should have the datepart you want in double quotes

```
DATEPART("hh",Date_Time)
```

I created a basic package

[image]

### OLE_SRC Generate datetimes

I used the following query to generate some data

```
SELECT
    dateadd(hh, D.rn, current_timestamp) AS Date_Time
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
    FROM sys.all_columns AS SAC
) D(rn);
```

### DER Compute Hour

I create a new column called `Hour` in the first Derived Column Transformation and use the expression. Note that column names are case sensitive.

```
DATEPART("hh",Date_Time)
```

[image]

### DER Compute Reff

There are a number of approaches to this. I went with the quick but poorly maintainable approach of using the ternary operator to identify the values for Reff

```
([Hour]  < 3) ? 0 : ([Hour]  < 6) ? 1 : ([Hour]  < 9) ? 3 : -1
```

Not knowing what Reff is, it seems like something that could be computed mathematically but however you arrive at the answer, it would go here.

Comment: Thanks Bilinkc, this is fantastic detail!! Exactly what I needed.  I've just changed the Expression to FLOOR(DATEPART("hh",Date_Time) / 3) in the same Compute Hour Module. Great!!